# Remove Span tag generated in asp.net text label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot remove the span tag which auto generated with the image tag.

Asp.net Code :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);


                SiteManagementService siteMng = new SiteManagementService();
                LogedUserDTO logedUser = siteMng.GetLogedUserByUserId(Session["UserLoginID"].ToString().Trim());

                LabelUser.Text = logedUser.FullName + " | " + logedUser.Company.CompanyDesc;
                **LabelImage.Text = "<img  src=\"" + siteMng.GetUserImageUrl() + logedUser.ProfileImage + "\"  class='img-avatar'  />";**
                LabelDatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                Session["UserAccessLevel"] = logedUser.UserGroupId;
                Session["UserCompanyId"] = logedUser.CompanyId;

                RepeaterMenu.DataSource = siteMng.GetMenuByUserGroup(logedUser.UserGroupId);
                RepeaterMenu.DataBind();

                LabelMasterFooter.Text = "© 2013 " + ResourceData.CompanyName + ". All rights reserved.";

            }
```

Front End Code :

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelImage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Generated HTML Code :

```
<span id="ContentPlaceHolderHeader_LabelImage"><img src="UploadedFiles/ProPicturs/Img_1711.JPG" class="img-avatar"></span>
```

**Code i want is just**

```
<img src="UploadedFiles/ProPicturs/Img_1711.JPG" class="img-avatar">
```

Comment: Use a `PlaceHolder` instead of a `Label`.

Comment: please add a code sample for PlaceHolder

Comment: wait... have you heard `asp:Image`..? it should generate `<image>` tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only use an image tag, there is an [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image?view=netframework-4.7.2) tag in asp.net

---

```
protected string image_tag; // add this var in your page class and set it as protected

...

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);


    SiteManagementService siteMng = new SiteManagementService();
    LogedUserDTO logedUser = siteMng.GetLogedUserByUserId(Session["UserLoginID"].ToString().Trim());

    LabelUser.Text = logedUser.FullName + " | " + logedUser.Company.CompanyDesc;
    image_tag = "<img  src=\"" + siteMng.GetUserImageUrl() + logedUser.ProfileImage + "\"  class='img-avatar'  />";
    LabelDatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Session["UserAccessLevel"] = logedUser.UserGroupId;
    Session["UserCompanyId"] = logedUser.CompanyId;

    RepeaterMenu.DataSource = siteMng.GetMenuByUserGroup(logedUser.UserGroupId);
    RepeaterMenu.DataBind();

    LabelMasterFooter.Text = "© 2013 " + ResourceData.CompanyName + ". All rights reserved.";

}
```

you can try to use in .aspx page.

```
<%= image_tag %>
```

instead of

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelImage" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Label Control will add a HTML element to the page. Either as a `div` or a `span` element. So this

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="MyLabel">
    Content...
</asp:Label>
```

Becomes this

```
<span id="Label1" class="MyLabel">
    Content...
</span>
```

But a PlaceHolder does not generate it's own html element. So the following code

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     Content...
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Will generate

```
Content...
```

But there are some downsides, as a PlaceHolder does not have a `CssClass` property.